# в пайтон не могу запустить код selenium wire

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

в python вылезает странная ошибка, будто у меня не установлена библиотека selenium wire, хотя я ее ни раз устанавливал:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\work\pythonProject\chromedriver\seleniumForm.py", line 1, in <module>
    from seleniumwire import webdriver


from seleniumwire import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--proxy-server=23.227.38.131:80")

proxy_options = {
        "proxy": {
            "http": "http://23.227.38.131:80",
            "https": "https://23.227.38.131:80",
        }
    }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        options=options,
        seleniumwire_options=proxy_options
    )

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```